# Make an action when you drop a div

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop

I want to emit an event throught socket whene the drop of the div is done. Here is code that i have tried , i couldn't change the event.

```html
<script>
  function dragIt(theEvent) {
    theEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", theEvent.target.id);
  }

  function dropIt(theEvent) {
    var theData = theEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var theDraggedElement = document.getElementById(theData);
    theEvent.target.appendChild(theDraggedElement);
    theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
<div id="parent-div" ondrop="dropIt(event);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
  <div class="myDIV myDIV1" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="myDIV">
    ARTEFACT2
  </div>
  <div class="myDIV myDIV2" class="ui-widget-content draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="myDIV2">
    ARTEFACT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `i couldn't change the event` Change to what?

Comment: whene i drop the div , i want to do " socket.emit('the _event...etc') "

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you do `socket.emit('the _event...etc')`? The error is with the `drop` event or with the `socket.emit` function?